# can people read the content of an online php file?

Tags: php, file-permissions

My php file online has permission settings 444 - ('readable' for everyone)

When I open the file in Firefox, it correctly only shows the output of the file (meaning things that are echoed or printed)

I want people to NOT EVER see the inside of the php file because it shows sensitive information. So - are there some people that are able to look into the inside of the php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone has access to the server then generally no.
There are ways to purposely make the source code visible however.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php